# Get the id after finding the order in the table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the `stop_id` of the last stop_name `GHI` in my `stops` table with this query but I am getting this error `Column 'stop_id' in field list is ambiguous` although I have this column in my  table.

**Query1:**

```
SELECT stop_id
FROM stops s1 
JOIN stops s2 ON s1.stop_id = s2.stop_id - 1
JOIN stops s3 ON s2.stop_id = s3.stop_id - 1
WHERE CONCAT(s1.name, s2.name, s3.name) = CONCAT('ABC','DEF','GHI')
```

When I tried it as below I got the result one.

**Query2:**

```
SELECT 1
FROM stops s1 
JOIN stops s2 ON s1.stop_id = s2.stop_id - 1
JOIN stops s3 ON s2.stop_id = s3.stop_id - 1
WHERE CONCAT(s1.name, s2.name, s3.name) = CONCAT('ABC','DEF','GHI')
```

**stops table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops
                    (stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                     name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
                    lat double(10,6) , 
                    longi double(10,6)
```

**Simple:**

```
1 ABC
2 DEF
3 GHI
4 JKL
5 MNO
6 PQR
7 SDU
8 VWX
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You join the table to itself multiple times, and need to specify, which table to use. In your case it will be the 3-rd table:

```
SELECT s3.stop_id
FROM stops s1 
JOIN stops s2 ON s1.stop_id = s2.stop_id - 1
JOIN stops s3 ON s2.stop_id = s3.stop_id - 1
WHERE CONCAT(s1.name, s2.name, s3.name) = CONCAT('ABC','DEF','GHI')
```

Answer (score 2):

ambiguous doesn't mean it's missing, it does mean that there are multiple possible columns in your joined tables. So you need to

```
SELECT table.stop_id ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In the statement `SELECT stop_id` *stop_id* can refer to the column in either `stops s1`, `stops s2` or `stops s3` so you have to specify which table you want it from, which would be `select s3.stop_id` in you case as you want `GHI`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify the column with proper table alias name saying `select s1.stop_id` else it's confusing to DB engine as to select the column from which table `stops s1` or `stops s2` and so the error thrown.

Your query should look like

```
SELECT s1.stop_id       <-- see s1 alias added
FROM stops s1 
JOIN stops s2 ON s1.stop_id = s2.stop_id - 1
JOIN stops s3 ON s2.stop_id = s3.stop_id - 1
WHERE CONCAT(s1.name, s2.name, s3.name) = CONCAT('ABC','DEF','GHI')
```